# Multipart upload in amazon s3 not calling delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I'm using multipart upload for file upload its working. But, not calling delegates how to call delegates.

Here my code:

```
AmazonS3Client *s31 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
            s31.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];
            s31.timeout = 240;
            @try
            {
                [s31 createBucketWithName:bucket];

                S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest *initReq = [[S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithKey:key inBucket:bucket];
                S3MultipartUpload *upload = [s31 initiateMultipartUpload:initReq].multipartUpload;
                S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest *compReq = [[S3CompleteMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];

                int numberOfParts = [self countParts:imageData];
                for ( int part = 0; part < numberOfParts; part++ ) {
                    NSData *dataForPart = [self getPart:part fromData:imageData];
                    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                    [appDelegate.dataArray addObject:dataForPart];

                    // The S3UploadInputStream was deprecated after the release of iOS6.
                    NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:dataForPart];
                    //if ( using3G ) {
                    // If connected via 3G "throttle" the stream.
                    //stream.delay = 0.2; // In seconds
                    //stream.packetSize = 16; // Number of 1K blocks
                    // }

                    S3UploadPartRequest *upReq = [[S3UploadPartRequest alloc] initWithMultipartUpload:upload];
                    upReq.partNumber = ( part + 1 );
                    upReq.contentLength = [dataForPart length];
                    upReq.stream = stream;

                    S3UploadPartResponse *response = [s31 uploadPart:upReq];
                    [compReq addPartWithPartNumber:( part + 1 ) withETag:response.etag];
                    NSLog(@"Coming222");
                }
                [s31 completeMultipartUpload:compReq];
                [self textfileupload];
            }
            @catch ( AmazonServiceException *exception )
            {
                isUpload=NO;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

                NSLog( @"Multipart Upload Failed, Reason: %@", exception  );
            }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to call delegate methods, you need to perform this, as with any objects that rely on delegate methods:

```
 putObjectRequest.delegate = self;
 [putObjectRequest setDelegate:self];
```

If you mean how you are using an instance of AppDelegate: `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`, then double check on if type casting as an AppDelegate pointer is the correct thing to do. Perhaps try another way of initializing/allocation, as I have run into issues with relying on a returned object typecasted into a cocoa pointer.